# Set a variable to value returned by a Python script

Tags: terraform

I have a pretty complicated calculation that is currently performed in Python. How can I can return the value from Python back to Terraform?

A contrived example:

```py
# calc.py
import sys
print(int(sys.argv[1]) + int(sys.argv[2]))
```

The closest thing I found is a `null_resource` with `local-exec` but it doesn't say anything about assigning the value back to a variable:

```
# main.tf
resource "null_resource" "run_python" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "python3 calc.py 1 2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This use case is essentially solved by the [external data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/data_source). You need to update your Python script to output a JSON-formatted string to `stdout` and accept JSON as input:

```
# calc.py
import sys
import json

# access values from stdin and parse json here
# pseudocode: use i.e. sys.stdin to assign the passed JSON string to i.e. variable named json_input
dict_input = json.loads(json_input)
arg1 = dict_input['arg1']
arg2 = dict_input['arg2']
# note that output keys and values must be string types
print(json.dumps({'my_data_key': str(int(arg1) + int(arg2))}))
```

and then use the `external_data_source` accordingly:

```
data "external" "python_calc" {
  program = ["python3", "${path.module}/calc.py"]

  query = {
    # arbitrary number of map(string), passed
    # to the external program as the data query.
    arg1 = "1"
    arg2 = "2"
  }
}
```

and then your value will be accessible in the namespace you would normally expect: `data.external.python_calc`. The exported resource attribute would be `result`, and then you can access key-value pairs as per normal: e.g. `data.external.python_calc.result.my_data_key`.

Comment: Interesting... my use case is a lot more complicated but I will try out the idea and report back. Thanks!